# Put a binary char array in a file C++

Tags: c++, file, buffer, iostream, bin

I'm writing a program where one server send binary messages to a client.
I receive the binary data sent by the server, but then I can't get it into a file correctly.
The objective is then to decrypt the file with openSSL.

Here is my code:

```
int     client::_writeFile()
{
    char    buf[bytes_received * bytes_received];
    recv(this->_socket, buf, bytes_received, 0);
    std::string const file("files/recv");
    std::ofstream f(file.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_received + 1; i++)
    {
        f.write(&buf[i],sizeof(buf[i]));
    }
    f.close();

    system("openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in files/recv -out files/decrypted.txt -pass pass:.key");
    
    return (SUCCESS);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "_but then I can't get it into a file correctly_": what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Also note that `char    buf[bytes_received * bytes_received];` looks suspicious. The size of arrays must be compile-time constants in standard C++ and why the number would be squared is not clear.

Comment: First, `recv` doesn't necessarily obtain exactly as many bytes as you've requested; you need to check its return value. Second, even assuming it did receive `bytes_received` bytes, you are writing `bytes_received+1` bytes to the file; the last byte is random garbage.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:cryptography] tag, as the question has nothing to do with the encryption command; please split your application in logical parts.\

Comment: also recv returns the actual number of bytes, you need to catpure  that. And where is bytes_received setup?

Comment: and writing one byte at a time in that loop in very inefficient

Comment: and you need to keep looping on recv until you have all the bytes

Comment: Thank you for you answers ! 

@user17732522 Sometimes the file is created with the desired content, sometimes it is truncated, sometimes it adds a lot of unwanted characters... I really don't understand.
For the size of the array, I just tried to put it on the number of bytes received, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you, I changed my loop ! But the problem persists.

It puts binary characters at the end of the file that are not in my buffer.

Comment: @pm100 I tried to write at one time ```f.write(buf, sizeof(buf));``` but without success

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but there is no need for that `file` variable. `std::ofstream f(“files/recv”, std::ios::binary);` will work just fine.

Comment: @Grahn "*I tried to write at one time f.write(buf, sizeof(buf)); but without success*" - that is because `sizeof` is the wrong value to use. Use the return value from `recv()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need something along these lines

```
char    buf[1000];
std::string const file("files/recv");
std::ofstream f(file.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
while(true){
   int count = recv(this->_socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
   if (count ==0)
      break;
    f.write(buf,count);
}
f.close();
```

this assumes that the remote end closes the connection once its finished sending the data